Indexedb not workin in Chrome
I have the following code. It runs perfectly on firefox and not working on the chrome. But if I open the developer tools, it even works on the chrome. What can be the issue?
function resetDatabase() {
            let request = indexedDB.deleteDatabase("CityDatabase4");

            request.onsuccess = function() {
                const cityVersion = 0; 
                localStorage.setItem('cityVersion', cityVersion);
                window.location.reload();
            };

            request.onerror = function() {
            };

            request.onblocked = function() {
            };
        }


I think window.location.reload() is probably the cause.

The issue likely stems from two key aspects of IndexedDB behavior

Connection handling. According to the spec, when deleting a database, all existing connections must be closed first. The onblocked event fires if other connections are still open when attempting to delete the database.

Chrome's behavior. Chrome may be maintaining some background connections that aren't immediately visible, which is why opening DevTools (which can force connection cleanup) makes it work.


Here's the corrected version of your code that should work consistently across browsers:
function resetDatabase() {
    // First, close any existing connections
    const DBOpenRequest = indexedDB.open("CityDatabase4");
    DBOpenRequest.onsuccess = function(event) {
        const db = event.target.result;
        db.close();
        
        // Now proceed with deletion
        let request = indexedDB.deleteDatabase("CityDatabase4");

        request.onsuccess = function() {
            const cityVersion = 0; 
            localStorage.setItem('cityVersion', cityVersion);
            window.location.reload();
        };

        request.onerror = function(event) {
            console.error("Error deleting database:", event.target.error);
        };

        request.onblocked = function(event) {
            console.log("Database deletion blocked");
        };
    };
}

Based on IndexedDB documentation states:

"If any of the connections in openConnections are still not closed, queue a task to fire a version change event named 'blocked' at request with db's version and null."

*see more: https://w3c.github.io/IndexedDB/#opening
This is why adding proper connection cleanup helps ensure consistent behavior across browsers.
Additional recommendations:

Add a timeout handling:

function resetDatabase() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const DBOpenRequest = indexedDB.open("CityDatabase4");
        const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
            reject(new Error("Database operation timed out"));
        }, 5000); // 5 second timeout

        DBOpenRequest.onsuccess = function(event) {
            const db = event.target.result;
            db.close();
            
            let request = indexedDB.deleteDatabase("CityDatabase4");

            request.onsuccess = function() {
                clearTimeout(timeout);
                const cityVersion = 0; 
                localStorage.setItem('cityVersion', cityVersion);
                resolve();
                window.location.reload();
            };

            request.onerror = function(event) {
                clearTimeout(timeout);
                reject(event.target.error);
            };

            request.onblocked = function(event) {
                clearTimeout(timeout);
                reject(new Error("Database deletion blocked"));
            };
        };

        DBOpenRequest.onerror = function(event) {
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            reject(event.target.error);
        };
    });
}


Consider adding a versionchange event listener to handle cases where the database might be deleted from another tab:

db.onversionchange = function() {
    db.close();
};

This should provide more reliable behavior across different browsers and scenarios.
